# how to specify a csl bibliography style on bookdown

Tags: r, markdown, bookdown

how to specify a csl  bibliography style on bookdown Chinese [Bookdown Chinese example](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese), for example a zotero one [CSL](https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=7714-2005-numeric).

I downloaded the csl file to the working directory, and specify it in index.Rmd YAML header as

```
bibliography: book.bib    
biblio-style: chinese-gb7714-2005-numeric
```

or

```
bibliography: book.bib
biblio-style: chinese-gb7714-2005-numeric.csl
```

but Rstudio promted me:

```
Error: Failed to build the bibliography via bibtex
Please delete bookdown.Rmd after you finish debugging the error.
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

when I changed it to

```
bibliography: book.bib
csl: chinese-gb7714-2005-numeric
```

or

```
bibliography: book.bib
csl: chinese-gb7714-2005-numeric.csl
```

I can build the book, however the reference list style was not the one the CSL expected.

All the YAML header

```
--- 
title: "题名"
author: "姓名"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
bibliography: book.bib
description: "矮脚黄"
documentclass: ctexbook
geometry:
- b5paper
- tmargin=2.5cm
- bmargin=2.5cm
- lmargin=3.5cm
- rmargin=2.5cm
github-repo: yihui/bookdown-chinese
indent: 2m
link-citations: yes
lof: no
lot: no
colorlinks: yes
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
biblio-style: unsrt
whitespace: none
---
```

updated:

today I found the header of Chapter reference was not correct. It should be "Reference" instead of the previous chapter's.
[image: Incorrect header]

Comment: Try `csl: chinese-gb7714-2005-numeric.csl` instead.

Comment: It is still the CSL expected. I updated the original post.

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your yaml?

Comment: updated. Many thanks

Comment: I am getting the same style as in the Zotero link you shared. Is indentation your problem?

Comment: Which line? I don't think so.

Comment: Here is what I see in the link you shared: https://imgur.com/9EhChRT. Here is what I am getting: https://imgur.com/0EKx4B5

Comment: Which line? I don't think so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use csl-file for pdf-output in bookdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965247/use-csl-file-for-pdf-output-in-bookdown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably missed two lines:

> - Set in _output.yml `citation_package: none`
> - Add in all formats (gitbook, pdf_book, epub_book) in _output.yml the line `pandoc_args: [ "--csl", "chinese-gb7714-2005-numeric.csl" ]`

See the full procedure at [use csl-file for pdf-output in bookdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965247/use-csl-file-for-pdf-output-in-bookdown/49145699#49145699)

Comment: There is one line in _output.yml. `  pandoc_args: "--top-level-division=chapter" 1 and I  revised is as ` pandoc_args: ["--top-level-`division=chapter", "--csl", "chinese-gb7714-2005-numeric.csl" ]` the citation in text is expected. However the section name `参考文献` `Reference` at the end of the book disappeared.

Comment: Replace the content of 06-references.Rmd with `# References {-}`

Comment: Many thanks. I made it after following the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965247/use-csl-file-for-pdf-output-in-bookdown/49145699#49145699

Comment: today I found the header of Chapter reference was not correct. It should be "Reference" instead of the previous chapter's.

Comment: I asked in another question. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663004/customize-or-remove-the-header-of-reference-after-specify-csl-on-bookdown