# Customize or remove the header of reference after specify csl on Bookdown

Tags: r, latex, markdown, bookdown

I specified a csl bibliography style as described by [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652853/how-to-specify-a-csl-bibliography-style-on-bookdown)
of `bookdown` [Chinese example](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese), and found the header for the Reference was incorrect, it should be "参考文献（Reference) instead of "附录（Appendix）" for the second page of Section Reference. [image: see the picture]

How can I customize it to 'Reference' or just remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the LaTeX command `\markboth{left page}{right page}` to set the page headings, i.e. something like this

````
# 参考文献 {#references .unnumbered}
\markboth{参考文献}{参考文献}

```{r include=FALSE}
# 自动生成 R 包的参考文献
knitr::write_bib(c(
  .packages(), 'bookdown', 'knitr', 'rmarkdown'
), 'packages.bib')
```
````