# RMarkdown/Bookdown: Output specific CSL (citation style)

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown, csl, pandoc-citeproc

Is there a possibility to specify different citation style language (CSL) files in (the *YAML* header of) *RMarkdown*?

I tried

```
---
output:
  bookdown::word_document2:
    csl: style_1.csl
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    csl: style_2.csl
---
```

but it doesn't result in different citation styles in the different output formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do it like that.  `csl` isn't an argument to the `bookdown::word_document2` function, or `rmarkdown::word_document`.

The `csl:` entry in the YAML needs to be at the top level, and is handled by Pandoc.  It might be possible to include it in the `pandoc_args` argument to the driver functions, but the normal way is to use
`csl: style.csl` at the top level, so you'd get the same style for both output formats.

Edited to add:

From your comment, `pandoc_args` does work.  You would use YAML like this:

```
---
output:
  bookdown::word_document2:
    pandoc_args: ["--csl=style_1.csl"]
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    pandoc_args: ["--csl=style_2.csl"]
---
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was not clear to me from the documentation. Using `pandoc_args: ["--csl=ieee2.csl"]` as you suggested and explained on <https://garrettgman.github.io/rmarkdown/word_document_format.html#pandoc-arguments> was exactly what I was looking for. I also thought of using a Pandoc filter (written in Lua) to adjust the CSL depending on the output format, but I'm not sure whether the YAML options are accessible by a filter.

Comment: A similar solution was also mentioned on <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965247/use-csl-file-for-pdf-output-in-bookdown?rq=1>, but I only saw it now.